# React Native : uri rendered multiple times in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm a newbie to react native. I try to add a flatlist to my app.
I hava an array of datas designed like that:

```
   ["https://hi.com//image.png",  //uri
    "hello",
    "https://hi.com//image2.png",
    "welcome",      
    "https://hi.com//image3.png",
    "great",      
      ../..
   ]
```

Problem is that my image shows up but the text in the right side is actually my uri stringyfied.

I think there's something wrong with the keyExtractor:

```
renderItem =({item}) => {           
return(    
  <View style ={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <Image source ={{uri: item}}/>
    <View style ={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
  )
}

render() {  
return (
  <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <FlatList 
        data= {this.state.dataSource}              
        keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem= {this.renderItem}
        /> 
  </View>       
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your renderItem function loops thru every single element of array, not sure its the best option for your kind of data, maybe try to use something like this instead

```
const data = [{uri: 'https://link.io', text: 'hello'},{uri: 'http://anotherlink.co', text: 'bye'}]
```

then inside your renderItem fuction pass data:

```
    <Image source ={{uri: item.uri}}/>
    <Text>{item.text}</Text>
```

on the other hand if your you need to keep flat array, maybe be write some function with modulo of deviding index by 2 and from there get what goes where, but not sure why would you need that apart maybe from codewars challange ;)
good luck, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I try your solution. How do you parse an array of strings to json objects with key/value peers? I used Json.parse(myArray) and it didn't work + I don't have peers

Comment: sorry didn't fully get your question, can you please provide sample data of what you have and what you want to have in the end

Comment: I finally found out how to do it. I used the push function

Answer (score 0):

your flatlist render item is trying to access the item in a loop.so everytime it gets looped,you are passing item to Image and item to Text.As @wijuwiju suggested,that is the best way to implement it.try to maintain keys to your data.Then your flatlist will render properly.

Answer (score 0):

Store Item Like this:

```
 profilePicture: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
```

Set Image Source Like this:

```
<Image source={{uri:profilePicture}}/>
```